# Shell searching the contents in a file

Tags: shell

I have a file: `abc.txt`.

Inside it there are many filenames like:

```
GMDCOM.27936.log
GMDCOM.33333.log
GMDCOM.44444.log
```

I want to search the contents of the `GMDCOM` files which are listed in `abc.txt` file. How to do it using normal Shell script without AWK, SED or PERL.

Comment: start with `grep -o GMDCOM abc.txt` you can pipe the output (list of ile names) as an input to the "search program"

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 2):

[`xargs`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xargs) command may help. It will take list of arguments on standard input and will run a command on each of them. For instance, `grep`:

```
cat file-with-list-of-filenames.txt | xargs grep word_I_want_to_find
```

Comment: I know. It's just, IMHO, `cat list | xargs foo` is more readable than `xargs foo < list`